# How to unserialize data which was sent by ajax?

Tags: php, serialization

The data looks like:

```
sport[]=1&music[]=0&web[]=2
```

I did:

```
$data = unserialize($post["data"]);
```

but this is an error:

```
ErrorException [ 8 ]: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 27 bytes ~ APPPATH\classes\controller\ajax.php [ 14 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str), like this:

```
parse_str( 'sport[]=1&music[]=0&web[]=2', $data);
```

Now `$data` contains the values from that string:

```
Array
(
    [sport] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [music] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [web] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: An explanation would be appropriate here: unserialize() doesn't work because the string is not in a PHP serialization format but looks like an HTTP query string. Serializing data with PHP's native serialization format isn't the AJAX way anyway; usually, an interoperable format like XML or JSON is used.

Answer (score -1):

`$_POST` and `$_GET` arrays already hold unserialized `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data from your request.

Go print a `var_dump()` of your `$_POST` array in order to see how to access such values.